# Which one is the right status to be a freelancer in france- SAS SASU EURL EIRL SARL?

Tags: france, freelance

When i try to research about what is the right status to work as a freelancer in France, I get few options but completely confused what is the right one.
Could you please let me know which one is the right option to choose out of these in france?
SAS SASU EURL EIRL SARL

My situation:
I am an IT consultant and working on CDI since 2 years.
At the moment holding a valid EU Bluecard.
Would like to do freelancing going forward.

Comment: SAS and SARL don't really make sense in this context, SAS and EURL are the corresponding status for individual freelancers. So SASU = SAS with one associate, EURL = SARL with one associate. SASU, EURL and EIRL all apply as does the "auto-entrepreneur" status. Beyond that, there are some differences in the paperwork involved, fiscal status, the consequences for your liability and that of your spouse. FWIW, the SAS(U) form is relatively new (1990s) and increasingly popular. Not sure the question is really on-topic, though.

Comment: AFAIK a French SARL requires at least two persons, so if you will be working solo you can probably rule out this possibility. A SASU could be more advantageous than a EURL depending on the compensation scheme. Fiscally they are treated quite differently.

Answer (score 1):

When I set up my business (Saas) it was quite obvious that a SAS would be the right choice. Sadly, I can't remember all the details (as there are many).

There is another option called micro-entrepreneur. It has some restrictions for whom it is possible, but it is by far the easiest way. One restriction is that you are not allowed to earn more than ~100k(???) per year. Also, it has quite some restrictions for tax deductions.

When deciding also look for the consequences for the costs of your social insurances.

Wish you the best for this endeavor and stay strong, setting up business in France is hard.

Comment: In 2020, the maximum yearly turnover for a *micro-entrepreneur* was €72k for intellectual services (consulting, etc.) and €176k if you deal with physical goods (be it as a retailer, producer, or services in the hospitaliy industry).

Comment: Yes. This micro-entrepreneur option does not work for me. 
1. Because i was looking for an option to deduct my company expenses to reduce the taxes.
2. My annual turnover would be more than €100K